# How to connect watson assistant to RPA (robotic process automation) services or orchestration services?

Tags: watson-assistant

I want to connect IBM Watson Assistant to an RPA (Robotic process automation) service or orchestration service so that the chatbot can automate manual processes like sending emails, making an appointment..., How can I connect Watson Assistant to an orchestration service?

Thanks

Comment: Check for custom extensions or webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach at the moment is to use  [Watson Assistant Custom Extension feature](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-call-extension).
There are additional documentation and tutorials [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-toolkit/tree/master/integrations/extensions)